# Fazer o SELECT retornar dados no idioma padrão quando não achar tradução

Tags: mysql

Estou montando uma base multi-idiomas.

Tenho um select com o idioma escolhido, mas não há garantia de que 100% do conteúdo esteja traduzido, então eu preciso fazer uma espécie de `or` para o idioma padrão como alternativa secundária.

```
select ...
 where ...
   and (idioma = 'pt-br' or idioma = 'en-us')
```

Há um relacionamento nessa consulta, mas não vem ao caso. O problema é que quando tenho entradas em ambos os idiomas, o `select` sempre retorna o com ID menor, no caso `en-us`:

```
id | idioma | texto
1  | en-us  | ...
2  | pt-br  | ...
3  | it     | ...
```

O que eu preciso é priorizar a linguagem desejada, e trazer a *default* apenas quando a desejada não for encontrada.

Comment: Se eu entendi o que você deseja fazer, poderia simplesmente dar um `ORDER BY id` e um `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @Oeslei, `ORDER BY language = 'pt-br'`?

Comment: Isso. Havia lido errado e entendido que você queria o menor id. Mas é exatamente isso que você colocou. Porém o order by não funciona assim. Tem uma forma de especificar strings no order by, mas não me recordo agora.

Comment: Vou testar também, dou um feed em breve.

Comment: ORDER BY language = 'linguagem default' é pra resolver. Pode ser != ou DESC, se for uma só, ou se forem várias, pode ordenar por FIND_IN_SET. Se estiver usando uma linguagem de programação gerenciando o SQL, pode até deixar  numa session (ou variável) a string de IDs de ordem de preferencia pronta, para evitar JOIN. (algo do tipo `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET( id_linguagem_do_post, $string_com_ids_em_ordem de preferencia )`

Comment: Valeu a dica @Bacco, sou limitadão com DB. Há bastante referencias postadas, e estou vendo uma por uma - vou ver agora a sua sobre `FIND_IN_SET`. TKS

Comment: O FIND_IN_SET vai ser mais ou menos assim, se a linguagem desejada for it, depois pt e por ultimo en-us se nao achar as anteriores: `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET( id_linguagem_da_postagem, '3,2,1') LIMIT 1` - pode ser 'it, pt-br, en-us' tambem, se quiser usar com JOIN, mas se for usar PHP ou alguma outra linguagem extra, vc monta o '3,2,1' uma vez só assim que o usuário logar, e guarda no aplicativo pra todas as queries em vez de sobrecarregar o SGDB a toda consulta.

Answer (score 5):

Se entendi direito, não tem nenhuma garantia de qual ID será retornado. Fica difícil dar uma resposta precisa sem saber mais do seu banco, mas eu faria um `JOIN` para o conteúdo em cada idioma (o escolhido e o default), e uma query nesta linha:

```
SELECT
   -- ...
   COALESCE(conteudo_en.texto, conteudo_pt.texto) AS texto
FROM paginas pagina
   INNER JOIN conteudos conteudo_pt
   ON conteudo_pt.pagina_id = pagina.id
   AND conteudo_pt.idioma = 'pt-br'
   LEFT OUTER JOIN conteudos conteudo_en
   ON conteudo_en.pagina_id = pagina.id
   AND conteudo_en.idioma = 'en-us'
WHERE pagina.id = 1
```

Comment: Esse é o problema, é `FROM cidade` e relacionamento em estado e país para pegar a tradução. De modo grosseiro: `estado.id = cidade.estado`, `pais.id = estado.id`

Comment: Mesmo uma queri simples ele retorna o menor id: `select * from cidade where idioma = 'en-us' or idioma = 'pt-br' and sid = 1 limit 1` e mesmo mudando a ordem não interfere no resultado. Não há prioridade na clausula OR?

Comment: Você vai precisar de algum tipo de condicional. No caso do meu exemplo com `JOIN` usei `COALESCE`, mas pode ser o caso de se fazer um `IF` ou `CASE` no `SELECT`. Não há prioridade no `OR` (que eu saiba). Você pode editar a pergunta incluindo a estrutura do banco e a query completa?

Comment: A tradução não fica em coluna como `conteudo_en`, fica em linha, então acho que COALESCE não serve. Uma sugestão que tive no SOEN foi dobrar o join um para cada idioma, mas acho meio porcalhão,se tiver 5 join's vou passar a ter 10... Vou tentar simplificar ou usar um exemplo mais simples, pois o DB é meio grandinho.

Comment: No meu exemplo, `conteudo_en` não é uma coluna, é uma tabela (um alias, na verdade)... @PapaCharlie

Comment: Desculpe, é verdade, não havia reparado. Vou ver se ajusto seu exemplo aqui pra rodar.

Comment: Inevitavelmente vou precisar de outro `LEFT OUTER JOIN` para o idioma padrão quando o escolhido não estiver disponível?

Comment: No padrão você usa INNER, e LEFT no escolhido. Mas essa solução requer sim ambos os joins, @PapaCharlie

Comment: Nessa query terei o retorno dos idiomas em EN e PT, e usarei apenas um (ou conteudo_en ou conteudo_pt) correto? Não é custoso em dados grandes?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar um `ORDER BY` e `LIMIT 1`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(idioma, 'en-us', 'pt-br'), idioma LIMIT 1
```

Nos valores da função `FIELD` você coloca primeiro o idioma que está buscando e depois o idioma padrão. [Mais informações](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/) sobre a função `FIELD`.

Comment: Se o idioma escolhido for *ar* ou *pt*, a ordem em relação a *en* será diferente... Nesse caso não seria sem `DESC`?

Comment: @PapaCharlie Você está certo! Acabei me descuidando no copy/paste, mas já atualizei a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

A solução com function seria algo do tipo (sem síntaxe apurada)

```
FUNCTION OBTER_PAGINA (PID,PIDIOMA)

 SELECT TEXTO
 FROM   TABELA
 WHERE ID = PID
 AND   IDIOMA = PIDIOMA;

 SE LOCALIZOU RETORNA TEXTO
 SE NAO LOCALIZOU
  SELECT TEXTO
  FROM   TABELA
  WHERE ID = PID
  AND   IDIOMA = 'EN-US;
  SE LOCALIZOU RETORNA TEXTO
  SE NAO LOCALIZOU RETORNA " "
```

No select algo do tipo

```
SELECT OBTER_PAGINA(1234,'PT-BR') FROM ...
```

Não é um código EXATAMENTE mas ideia básica de trabalhar a questão, a vantagem é que a implementação da busca pelo texto fica encapsulada na FUNCTION.

Comment: nesse caso a query é exatamente a mesma, só muda o idioma, certo? Nunca usei essa forma, você tem alguma DOC pra eu consultar?

Comment: http://sql-info.de/mysql/examples/create-function-examples.html       http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-functions.html  Não, pois não trabalho com MySql mas creio que o manual básico te ajude

Answer (score 1):

Você pode buscar o idioma desejado (*en-us*) **ou** o idioma padrão (*pt-br*) **caso** o idioma desejado não esteja presente. Para esta última condição você pode usar a clásula **not exists** sobre uma subquery conectada com a query principal.

Não ficou claro para mim em qual coluna você se baseará para buscar a tradução, então vou usar uma tabela hipotética e você pode usar a técnica adptando o código para sua tabela real.

Tabela:

```
id | idioma | texto_original | texto_traduzido
1  | en-us  | ...            | ...
2  | pt-br  | ...            | ...
3  | it     | ...            | ...
```

Comando SQL:

```
select 
    texto_traduzido
from 
    traduções
where
    (
        texto_original = 'casa'
        and idioma = 'en-us'
    )
    or 
    (
        texto_original = 'casa'
        and idioma = 'pt-br'
        and not exists
        (
            select 
                texto_original
            from 
                traduções as idioma_desejado
            where
                idioma_desejado.texto_original = traduções.texto_original
                and idioma_desejado.idioma = 'en-us'
        )
    )
```

<sub>Minha indentação deixou a query grande mas ela é na verdade bastante simples.</sub>

Comment: É algo simples, não há `texto_original`, apenas *idioma* e *texto*, por isso precisa buscar o idioma escolhido ou o *default*, para os casos em que não houver tradução. No exemplo, o 1º `and idioma` não deveria ser `PT-BR`? Sou bem raso com MYSQL.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Qual é o filtro? `ID`? Neste caso ID repete para cada idioma, certo? Eu inventei "idioma_original" porque não sei qual é o filtro, além do idioma, que você vai usar para selecionar um texto.

Comment: Peguei a ideia, vou rodar aqui ja ja.

Comment: De qualquer modo a resposta do @bfavaretto já deveria resolver; eu só dei uma opção. Esta minha query usando JOIN ficaria assim: `select  coalesce(idioma_desejado.texto_traduzido, idioma_padrao.texto_traduzido) from  traduções as idioma_padrao left join traduções as idioma_desejado  on idioma_desejado.texto_original = idioma_padrao.texto_original and idioma_desejado.idioma = 'en-us' where idioma_padrao.idioma = 'pt-br' and idioma_padrao.texto_original = 'casa'`. Se não conseguiu aplicar nenhuma das duas, complete sua pergunta com os dados das tabelas e sua query atual.

Comment: Toda ajuda é bem vinda, estou de olho em todas. O problema de colocar todo DB é que é grande, tem relacionamentos e eu optei em explicar mais simples pra poder adaptar à cada necessidade. Mas se realmente fou preciso eu altero para o mais próximo e fácil de explicar.

Comment: Muitos colegas não gostam deste tipo de solução mas eu testaria uma FUNCTION que receberia os parametros de busca e retornaria a string tratando esta questão do idioma , testa com pt-br não achando testa com en-us ....